# Cannot install latest version of Flash

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, flash

I am trying to update Flash Player on my laptop running Windows xP SP2.

File: install_flashplayer16x32_mssd_aaa_aih.exe

The installer window opens but no text appears and it just remains on the screen.

Manually closing the window, Firefox opens with this message:

"Server not found. Firefox can't find the server at www.{completionpageurl}.com."

I've tried uninstalling Flash but get the same repsonse.

On the Adobe Flash Player page I have been unticking the McAfee Security Scan Plus option.

I've gone back to an old version of Flash thats still on my laptop:

install_flash_player.exe - File version: 10.2.152.32

This loads okay.

Any ideas/suggestions why I cannot load the latest version?

Thanks
G

Comment: The first step to accomplish your goal is to install the `Windows XP SP3` update.

Comment: And then install from https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html

Comment: I am reluctant to install SP3, as I have aquired the laptop with no Windows disks and no idea of its history. I do not want to try to install SP3 in case it renders the laptop unusable.

Comment: The System Requirements on the Abode Flash install page does not mention needing Service Pack 3, it just says XP.

Comment: @Graham I believe that today it's taken for granted that a user should be running SP3 if he/she is still on Windows XP.

Comment: If you're worried about losing XP, since you have no backup or installation media, you might test a newer OS, such as free Linux, from a USB drive. This is not a direct answer to your question, I realize, but consider migration from no-longer-supported XP.

Comment: Open Internet Explorer and try to [install the latest version from this page](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/), be sure to un-tick the optional offers.

Answer (score -1):

DON'T install Service Pack 3 for XP, your machine will slow down to nearly unusable speeds. Just update your `.NETfix packages` and `Installer packages` from Microsofts support webpages by themselves. Then download the full flash player for your browser from Adobe's archives at https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html